# How do I remove stop words from an arraylist of strings in python?

Tags: python, nltk, text-analysis

I would like to remove stop words from the arraylist named arrayList1, which is stored in the data variable. 
I try the below method but it does not work. Please help me check the below codes and improve the codes.Thanks.

```
import Retrieve_ED_Notes
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

data = Retrieve_ED_Notes.arrayList1

stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))


def remove_stopwords(data):
 data = [word for word in data if word not in stop_words]
 return data

for i in range(0, len(remove_stopwords(data))):
  print(remove_stopwords(data[i]))
```

Console output of the arrayList1:

```
1|I really love writing journals
2|The mat is very comfortable and I will buy it again likes
3|The mousepad is smooth
1|I really love writing journals
4|This pen is very special to me.
4|This pencil is very special to me.
5|Meaningful novels
4|It brights up my day like a lighter and makes me higher.
6|School foolscap
7|As soft as my heart.lovey
```

Comment: can you post sample of `arrayList1` and `data ` and expected output

Comment: try `data = [word for word in data if word.lower() not in stop_words]`

Comment: @pyd hi I have already added the output of the arrayList! Please help me take a look and the above codes you gave does not work :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

convert the word to lower and check with stopwords.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords=set(stopwords.words('english'))

data =['I really love writing journals','The mat is very comfortable and I will buy it again likes','The mousepad is smooth']

def remove_stopwords(data):
    output_array=[]
    for sentence in data:
        temp_list=[]
        for word in sentence.split():
            if word.lower() not in stopwords:
                temp_list.append(word)
        output_array.append(' '.join(temp_list))
    return output_array

output=remove_stopwords(data)

print(output)
['really love writing journals','mat comfortable buy likes', 'mousepad smooth']
```

Comment: There are errors  
    output = remove_stopwords(data)
, line 14, in remove_stopwords
    if word.lower() not in stopwords:
TypeError: argument of type 'WordListCorpusReader' is not iterable @pyd

Comment: what is your type of arraylist, `print(type(arraylist1))`

Comment: <class 'list'> @pyd is an arrayList1 in a data variable if u look at my codes

Comment: I edited the code, pls check, converted stopwords to set format

Comment: you changed `stopwords=stopwords.words('english')` to `stopwords=set(stopwords.words('english'))`

Comment: yup I have changed